# Mender.io error while running from source?

Tags: raspberry-pi3, imx6

I am trying to get Mender.io working, a remote updating system.
I just want to see the device appear on the server, somehow thats not happening.
I installed mender from source on apalis imx6, I am trying to run it like :
mender -daemon

It starts up fine, then gives me the following errors :

```
INFO[0180] State transition: check-wait [Idle] -> inventory-update [Sync]  module=mender
ERRO[0180] Cannot determine current artifact. Update will continue anyways: /var/lib/mender/device_type : open /etc/mender/artifact_info: no such file or directory  module=mender
ERRO[0180] failed to submit inventory data: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "x509: ECDSA verification failure" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "docker.mender.io")  module=client_inventory
WARN[0180] failed to refresh inventory: failed to submit inventory data: inventory submit failed: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "x509: ECDSA verification failure" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "docker.mender.io")  module=state
INFO[0180] State transition: inventory-update [Sync] -> check-wait [Idle]  module=mender
INFO[0180] State transition: check-wait [Idle] -> update-check [Sync]  module=mender
ERRO[0180] could not get the current artifact name       module=mender
ERRO[0180] Error receiving scheduled update data: update check request failed: Get https://docker.mender.io//api/devices/v1/deployments/device/deployments/next: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "x509: ECDSA verification failure" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "docker.mender.io")  module=mender
ERRO[0180] update check failed: transient error: update check request failed: Get https://docker.mender.io//api/devices/v1/deployments/device/deployments/next: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "x509: ECDSA verification failure" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "docker.mender.io")  module=state
INFO[0180] State transition: update-check [Sync] -> error [Error]  module=mender
INFO[0180] handling error state, current error: transient error: update check request failed: Get https://docker.mender.io//api/devices/v1/deployments/device/deployments/next: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "x509: ECDSA verification failure" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "docker.mender.io")
```

I have added the certificate generated using the keygen provided in etc/mender/server.crt and started up docker server using ./up
I don't see my device under devices either.

What else could I do?

Comment: Perhaps the problem is the "x509: ECDSA verification failure"?

It would be interesting to know if you get this resolved so if you get this resolved, please let us know.  (Also, I'm wondering if this question could be phrased differently to get some more responses and perhaps help others as well though I don't have any specific suggestions unfortunately.  It seems your question is "What else can I do?" so perhaps a more specific question may help.)

Comment: Hi, I was able to get it connected to the server, the server sends a 401 not authorized back to the mender client. Mender client does have authorization to connect, which is normal problem being I cannot see the device authorization request on the mender server, which is normally supposed to happen.

Comment: I dont have any artifact yet, but I figured it should at least be able to authorize itself and appear on the server UI. I was able to get this working for SWupdate tough.

Comment: For the specific error you included in your original error log, you can try the "skipverify" option: `mender -daemon -skipverify`

That should confirm whether or not it is a certificate problem.  If it is a certificate problem, you may need to replace the certificate in the image you're using with one appropriate for your server (and/or provide it explicitly using the appropriate command line option)

For the 401 not authorized you mention later, I'd need to see the actual error logs to try to decipher what actually happened.